# Best functional approach to AND across a list

Tags: ruby

Suppose I have an array of values [a,b,c,d,...] and a function f(x,...) which returns true or false.

```
[1,2,3,4].map {|x| f(x)}  => [true true false true]
```

First, what is the best way to collapse the resultant list into a true or false value (via AND)?  Is there a function that would allow me to map:

```
[true true false true]
```

to:

```
((true && true) && false) && true
```

using a cumulative pair-wise application of the binary && operator?

In this case the cost of evaluating the function is substancial, so would like to use a lisp-style "and" to evaluate the arguments (function applications) sequentially until one of them is false.   Determined that could do:

```
!![1,2,3,4].each {|x| break false if !f(x) }
```

Which is ugly.   Hoping that there is a more elegant way to do this.   I am aware that I could add a new comprehension to Array, but hoping that there is something built-in that does this better.  Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're looking for `Enumerable#all?`, which returns true if all of the invocations of its block are truthy.  There is also `Enumerable#any?`, which returns true if any of the invocations of its block are truthy:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby1.8

def even(n)
  n % 2 == 0
end

p [1, 2, 3, 4].all? { |i| even(i) }    # => false
p [2, 4, 6, 8].all? { |i| even(i) }    # => true
p [1, 2, 3, 4].any? { |i| even(i) }    # => true
p [1, 3, 5, 7].any? { |i| even(i) }    # => false
```

`any?` short-curcuits: the first truthy value causes it to return true.  So does `all?` short circuit: the first falsy value causes it to return false.

Comment: Sorry for nitpicking, but `Fixnum` already has methods `even?` and `odd?`... ;)

Comment: @Mladen Jablanovic, Good point.  For this example I wanted a user-defined function.

Answer (score 3):

You could try folding your array:

```
[true,true,false,true].inject(:&) #=> false (AND-ed)
[true,true,false,true].inject(:|) #=> true  (OR-ed)
[1,2,3,4].inject(:+)              #=> 10    (summed)
[1,2,3,4].inject(:*)              #=> 24    (multiplied)
```

You get the clue. Back to your example:

```
[1,2,3,4].map {|x| f(x) }.inject(:&)
```

However it won't shortcircuit - you probably better look into "any?" or "all?" except your "f()" has side-effects (like modifying a persistent storage).

Comment: Thanks, this answers the first question! Wayne's answers the second.

Answer (score 1):

How about: `[true, true, false, true].all?`

This will return true if the array does not contain anything that evaluates to false or nil.